# EASA PPL theory instrumental approaches rules

Tags: ppl, theory

I am learning for EASA PPL in Czech.
I noticed that in some of the books there is chapters about Instrumental Approaches Air Law rules.
For example -

- ILS approaches
- Parallel approaches
- Simple Precision
- Non-Precision Approach vs Precision Approach
- Simple Approach systems vs Cat I, II//III systems
  but in most of the PPL material that I saw, no one talking about these subjects.

should I know these subjects for PPL ?

Comment: In the USA IFR procedures are not expected to be known by VFR only private pilots.  If as you say the PPL material you are studying does not mention IFR approaches, what makes you think that EASA would require it?  Isn't the scope of PPL knowledge or requirements published somewhere?

Comment: It's exactly the probelm, I cant find anywhere the requirements of EASA PPL ...

Comment: Well, is it safe to presume you started here?  https://www.easa.europa.eu/domains/general-aviation/licensing-general-aviation